# Using IF in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone tell me if this is the correct way to phrase this VBA macro?

The idea is for it to examine all cells in the range A2:A70 (actually, could be all of column A if it easier) and if the text of FA_Win_2 or FA_Win_3 is there, make the cell bold.

```
If Range(“A2:A70”) = FA_Win_2 Or _
   Range(“A2:A70”) = FA_Win_3 Then
   Range(“A2:A70”).font.Bold = “True”
End If
```

I have tried different things like enclosing the FA_Win_2 in "", adding .Value after the range, but am always coming up with compile errors.

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

cheers

Comment: You need to loop the range and test each cell individually.

Comment: Note that you are using invalid quotes `“ ”` these arae not allowed in VBA change them to the regular ones `" "`! The fancy ones you are using do not work.

Answer (score 1):

## Check Range for Values

### For Next Loop

```
Sub ForNext()

    Dim i As Long   ' Source Column Range Cells Counter

    ' In Source Column Range
    With Range(A2:A70)
        ' Loop through cells of Source Column Range.
        For i = 1 To .Cells.Count
            ' Check for Search Criterias.
            If .Cells(i) = "FA_Win_2" Or .Cells(i) = "FA_Win_3" Then
                ' Apply formatting.
                .Cells(i).Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

### For Each Loop

```
Sub ForEach()

    Dim Cell As Range   ' Current Cell Range (For Each Control Variable)

    ' Loop through cells of Source Column Range.
    For Each Cell In Range("A2:A70")
        ' Check for Search Criterias.
        If Cell = "FA_Win_2" Or Cell = "FA_Win_3" Then
            ' Apply formatting.
            Cell.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

## EDIT

### For Each Loop 2

```
Sub ForEach2()

    Const cSheet As String = "Sheet3"   ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const cRange As String = "A2:A70"   ' Source Column Range Address
    Const cStr1 As String = "FA_Win_2"  ' Search Criteria 1"
    Const cStr2 As String = "FA_Win_3"  ' Search Criteria 2"

    Dim Cell As Range   ' Current Cell Range (For Each Control Variable)

    ' Loop through cells of Source Column Range in Source Worksheet.
    For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cRange)
        ' Check for Search Criterias.
        If Cell = cStr1 Or Cell = cStr2 Then
            ' Apply formatting.
            With Cell
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)    ' White
                .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 255)  ' Pink
            End With
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @urdearboy: FE: 11, FN: 13, Y: 22, YFE: 17 and this time ms (mili seconds) of course. As we both knew, nothing unbearable.

Comment: @urdearboy: I don't thinks so. You just do your thing, be creative and when an efficiency issue occurs, you'll know how to solve it anyway. I've encountered something similar with **CountIf** against **Match** where **CountIf** does the whole range for each value, but **Match** stops as soon a value is found.

Comment: Just so you know, neither of the For Next Loop of For Each Loop solutions above did anything to the cells in column A, so not able to use those as is. A shame, as they add the ability to use multiple formats, like cell and font color

Comment: @honkin: I don't know how you have used them, but for starters you should use **Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range** ("Sheet3" mentioned in the comments) instead of **Range** and not forget to change the values for the **FA_Win..** constants or lose them, but you have to add **Const cRange As String = "A2:A70"**..

Comment: Apologies @Vbasic2008; this is one part of Excel I am extremely new to. I simply copied and pasted your code as is to the code area. 

So the Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range would go above the Const cRange As String line or is it just before the "A2:A70"?

Not entirely sure what values to use for the FA_Win.. variables as I don't know what it is saying. You had =2 and =3 respectively initially

Regards

Comment: @honkin: I've also noticed that you're using **"True"** in your code while it has to be **True** without the double quotes (**""**).

Comment: @honkin: What are the values of the **FA_Win_2** and **FA_Win_3** variables? I need this to edit my answer with a working solution. You should use the second solution using **For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(cRange)**.

Comment: @honkin: If **FA_Win_2** and **FA_Win_3** are values that you are searching, then you have to remove the two of the Const lines and replace them in the rest of the code with double quotes versions: **"FA_Win_2"** and **"FA_Win_3"**.

Comment: @Vbasic2009: I'm not sure I understand by values. They are both text input in cells in column A along with many other cells in column A which will have different text. If that text appears, the cells are formatted. Actually, the ultimate aim is if any cell in column B has today's date and the cell alongside it, so B2 and A2, if A2 has either FA_Win_2 or FA_Win_3, then it is formatted.

Comment: I had initially written some code which handled it really well using conditional formatting, but it gets messed up after a days when new data is pasted in and old data deleted. The conditional formatting went all over the place, so I turned to VBA.

The format of the cells in column B is d/m/yyyy hh:mm so I used =AND(TEXT($B2,"dd/mm/yyyy")=TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy") in my original conditional formatting formula.

So in essence, when the file is opened, if a cell in column B has today's date and the cell next to it in column A has that text, then it is formatted.

Comment: @honkin: I've added another solution **ForEach2**.

Comment: @Vbasic2008. That is absolutely perfect. Thanks so much for your help. I can just run that daily as data changes and it will indicate which cells are the ones required>

Thanks again

Comment: please accept this solution as it best fits your needs. This will give some points to both you and @VBasic2008 and is in the spirit of stack overflow to give credit to those who have helped you solve your task :)

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to set the `.Font.Bold = TRUE/FALSE` equal to your test statement.

I'm not sure if you really only need to loop through this range, but you can easily update to make this more dynamic by swapping the `70` to a variable last row calc

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim i as Long

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- Update
    For i = 2 To 70
        .Range("A" & i).Font.Bold = .Range("A" & i) = "FA_Win_2" Or .Range("A" & i) = "FA_Win_3"
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: So to also colour the text and cell, is it just a matter of using AND after .Font.Bold kind of like this AND .Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) AND .Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) or does it need the full .Range statmeent for each?

Comment: Any idea why this is less efficient (slower) than the For Each approach?

Comment: `For Each` loops are faster & would be an improvement to this solution @VBasic2008

Comment: @honkin no, you will have to have two different statements to apply multiple formats which kind of renders this solution not ideal since you don't want to have to repeatedly spam a test when the answer is already known. I'd also like to ask, why not just use `conditional formatting`?

Comment: The problem is you approach, it is doing something ('applying font') to all cells, while the if approach does it only to the ones that meet the criteria. In A2:A50000, For Each did 3.3 sec, For Next did 4.1, your solution did 10.5 sec, your solution in For Each did 7.7, using 'random' values from 1 to 5. All this doesn't matter, I upvoted anyway, because the approach would have never occurred to me. Might become useful in the future. Thx.

Comment: That's interesting - i'm really applying `TRUE/FALSE` to the `Font.` statement. Surprised to see such a jump - I may reconsider using this approach as this is how I implement tasks like this on my own. Although, on data sets as large as your tests, I would never format the raw data in the first place.... So on ranges that are small enough to justify formats (IMO), the gains are likely to be extremely minimal. Thanks for timing! @VBasic2008

Comment: With that being said, I wouldn't call this approach a problem. If people are formatting data sizes on that scale, they are prob doing analysis wrong in the first place. Would anyone really scroll through 50K rows to find the bold ones? Doubtful. They would work with the aggregated data instead that demands no formatting.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments 

undearboy, I initially did use conditional formatting. 

    =AND(TEXT($B2,"dd/mm/yyyy")=TEXT(TODAY(),"dd/mm/yyyy"), OR($A2="FA_Win_3", $A2="FA_Win_2"))

The issue is the data changes daily; copied and pasted from other sheets. The conditional formatting ends up all over the place. Instead of one rule applying to A2:A70, there might be three or four rules after a week, with each applying to incorrect cells. Data is copied from other sheets and pasted into this one daily. That didn't work well for more than a day. I can run the macro daily to at least help